# How To Host An Image With Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

## Issue

**How do I host an image file with Firebase hosting?**

I'm currently going through the steps in Firebase *In App Messaging* to setup messages to show to the user within the app. When asked to provide an *Image URL* for the message the UI suggests using [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart?authuser=0). I have followed the setup instructions and have successfully hosted my first site.

I cannot find documentation regarding hosting an image resources such as a *png* file that can route to a specific URL.

[image]

## Setup

### Hosting Configuration

[image]

### Hosting Success

[image]

Comment: How about the "Open Hosting Documentation" link?

Comment: Yes, @RobertHarvey, that routes to the same documentation linked above. The documentation must assume one knows how to host images. However, I'm an Android Developer so any tips would be appreciated :-)

Comment: You are correct @RobertHarvey. This is indeed not *Firebase Hosting Technical Support*. StackOverflow is a Question and Answer platform for enthusiast and professional developers. The issue defined above is regarding a lack of clarity in a portion of documentation. I hope this is useful for others who come across the same issue. Thank you for the ideas above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Solution

Under the *public* directory which is the default directory when initializing Firebase Hosting, simply add the image resource file such as a *png.*

Once the resources are deployed you can refer to the resource in the url.

## File Structure

[image]

## Url To Image

https://*your-project-name*.firebaseapp.com/*your-image*.png

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working fine, however if you have images under /assets/images that doesn't seem to b working

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) for storing **files** such as images.

❗️Loading times will be slower, due to the need of the request, but you can change images on your website without having to redeploy it (like switch `logo.png` for another image and it will just change on the website).

You can upload them manually in console and then retrieve them with Javascript:

```js
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'images/stars.jpg'))
  .then((url) => {
    // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

    // insert into an <img> element
    const img = document.getElementById('myimg');
    img.setAttribute('src', url);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
  });
```

⬇️

From [Google Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)