# Can Firebase Cloud Storage be used as the host for Flutter app content (images)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a wallpaper app where the contents are going to be high-res images made by my team not from the network. Images need to be displayed in the app. Users can scroll through all images; they can apply as wallpaper, download them, or select them as their favourite.

UI is ready. I am using Firebase for Authentication. I have worked with Firestore to add users to the database. Now I need to store those high-res images somewhere that I can get access to through the code.

Any suggestion that I can achieve this?

I am new to the backend. I have read the document related to Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage on FlutterFire and some other articles related to uploading images in the cloud storage through the firebase console and still haven't got a solution!

> Cloud Storage: store and serve user-generated content, such as photos and videos.

Does that mean cloud storage is only used for uploading images through the code inside the app and then being able to retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Storage is most commonly used for hosting user-generated content, such as when your users are submitting their own (candidate) wallpaper images.

If you yourself provide all the wallpaper images, you definitely *can* store them in Cloud Storage too, but I'd also consider storing them in Firebase Hosting, which has a much bigger content delivery network than Cloud Storage does.

Comment: How can I use Firebase Hosting to store images/files and display them in the mobile app? I have been checking the documents and googling to find any related article, but this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327092/how-to-host-an-image-with-firebase-hosting) is the only thing I saw. I appreciate any resources or clue on what should I do in my case?

Comment: Once you upload a file to hosting it becomes just another file on the internet, with its own URL. If you use that URL in your application, you can access the data of the file from Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. To upload the file, I tried to add my files to the `public` folder and deploy them from that directory. Not sure if that is the right way as I couldn't find any sample or guide to follow. Now, how do I know they are uploaded? How can I display those files in the app? What would be the URL? I have these two domains in my Firebase console > Hosting > Dashboard: `my-app-id.web.app` and `my-app-id.firebaseapp.com` if that helps.

Comment: The URL for each file will be something like `https://my-app-id.web.app/path/to/file.png`, so you'd include that in your application code and then load it from the URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=load+image+from+url+in+flutter